# changing instance variable's name in controller and view breaks the rspec tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have a very strange situation with an instance variable. I am in controller and I have this action

```
def index
  @categories = Category.main_categories
end
```

in the view I have this

```
<% @categories.each do |category| %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

and works like a charm

when I change the variable name from `@categories` to `@main_categories` (both in controller and view) I get this error

`ActionView::Template::Error:
   undefined method 'each' for nil:NilClass`

I tried the same (change the instance variable's name) with others controllers and views and it works.

This happen only in testing environment,
In development environment it works

My test file:

```
require "rails_helper"

RSpec.feature "Dashboard categories", :type => :feature do

let!(:menu_1) { create(:category) }
let!(:menu_2) { create(:dso) }
let!(:menu_3) { create(:stargazing) }
let!(:sub_menu_1_a) { create(:planets) }
let!(:sub_menu_1_b) { create(:asteroid) }
let!(:sub_sub_menu_1_a) { create(:mars) }
let!(:user) { create(:user) }

context "when visited by a not authorized user, " do
    scenario "it should contains a message to sign in" do
        visit "/dashboard/categories"
        expect(page).to have_text(/You need to sign in or sign up before continuing/)
    end
end

context "when visited by an authorized user," do
    before do
        sign_in user
        visit "/dashboard/categories"
    end

    scenario "it should contains all main and sub categories" do
        expect(page).to have_css('tr', count: 6)
        expect(page).to have_css('tr.subcategory', count: 3)
    end
end

end
```

Any idea what I do wrong?

Comment: Please, check one time more that you changed instance variable name in all places. It seems like you forgot to change name in view and called `each` on it.

Comment: I triple-checked it. Is there any other place except views I should check?

Comment: In which line error happened? Please, write full error stack trace.

Comment: Failure/Error: <% @main_categories.each do |category| %>

Comment: Is the `index` code the same as you provided in the question?

Comment: when I get the error `Failure/Error: <% @main_categories.each do |category| %>`  the code in the index is `@main_categories = Category.main_categories`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138547/discussion-between-ilya-and-stupid-one).